# Is the public modifier redundant inside a package private class?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class Test declared in Test.java in package `com.test`:

```
class Test {
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

I was wondering, isn't the public access-modifier for the method `test()` redundant here? Because intellij doesn't give me a hint saying that it is.

I thought it's not redundant only if the class `Test` contains `public static void main(String[] args) {}` Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not redundant. If you have some derivative classes then the modifier makes a huge difference. Consider the classes:

```
package ex.one

class Test {
    public void testPublic() {

    }

    void testPackage() {

    }    
}
```

and another class which derives the Test.class

```
package ex.one

public class TestDerivate extends Test {

    private void doSomething(){
        //legal
        testPublic();
        testPackage();
    }

}
```

Now when we have another class which derives TestDerivate.class then you can see a different behaviour on the methods. In this case this class has a public modifier.

```
package ex.two

public class TestDerivateInOtherPackage extends TestDerivate {
    public void test(){
         // legal
         testPublic();
         //illegal since it is only package visible
         testPackage();
    }

    @Override
    public void testPublic() {
        // still legal
    }

    @Override
    void testPackage() {
        // still illegal
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, how about if the class is final then?

Comment: That's a real good question. When the class is final and package visible, then no subclasses exist. In this case, the public method `testPublic()` would have the same visibility constraints as the package visibile method `testPackage()`. But I would recommend to use the public modifier because it makes the class easier to read and shows, that the public methods should be called.

Comment: Intellij doesn't say that 'public' is redundant here, though, but I think it should warn about this.

Answer (score 1):

any class may implement an *interface*. The latter contains declarations of methods which are always `public`. Furthermore you cannot reduce the visibility of an interface method.

Therefore it must be possible to declare a `public` method within a *non public* class.

Answer (score 0):

It's not redundant, because if you did have an object of type `Test` outside of the package, the `public` modifier could make the method visible even though the class itself is not.

In practice this is pretty rare. As one example, if you have another class `Test2` (in the same package) which extended from `Test` and was itself a public class, then the `public` modifier or lack of it would affect whether code outside the package could invoke `test()` on objects of type `Test2`.

The other, more common case would be if `Test` implemented an interface; then the method would have to be `public`, likewise to allow the method itself to be visible outside the package, where the class itself may not be visible but the interface may be.